# POP3 service is not ready even though the service is running, Telnet does not return POP3 OK status?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, telnet, pop3

I am working on a Windows 2008 R2 server running Exchange 2010 and I am currently trying to troubleshoot a POP3 connectivity issue that is preventing some outside remote accounts from logging into the mail server. The certificates are valid and I have verified from ExchangeShell. I have also the correct Exchange cert CN as the x509 certificate name. As well as verified the POP3 service is running also from ExchangeShell.

I cannot get a POP3 OK from a telnet session via running `telnet localhost 110`.

The only thing I am returned is:

`220 <localhost> Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at <date> -0500`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using POP instead of Outlook Anywhere?

Comment: This client uses a programmatic mail receiver that connects to exchange accounts to process emails and extract attachments accordingly.

Comment: If you got 

    220 <localhost> Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at <date> -0500

It looks like if you are using the SMTP service on port 110. If you read the following link [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789740(v=exchg.80).aspx) the correct response on port 110 should be:

    OK Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 POP3 service ready

So please follow this howto [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123530(v=exchg.150).aspx) to make sure you do not use port 110 as SMTP port.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Its odd because I get that response on both 110 and 995. I will look into that link. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @brndng if you login into your Exchange server via RDP and try a _telnet localhost 110_ did you get the same ESMTP response? Then it look like its a wrong port configuration.

Comment: @BastianW Thank you for the heads up. I will look into the port configuration. All of the ports are bound correctly for POP3 as well.